# GCP doesn't allow me to create a new project even if no other project is active

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying out GCP and I have run into this issue.
I shut down all active projects and now I want to create a new one but it says I have reached the quota. There are no active projects, all of the projects are scheduled for deletion.
I can restore an empty project (or any other project pending deletion) and it will work, but I cannot create a new one through the GUI or through the CLI.
How can that be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of projects that you can create is limited by the project limit quota. When you delete a project, the project is moved to a deleted status but not removed from your account for 30 days. You can recover a deleted project during those 30 days. The quota is the combined number of active and deleleted projects.

You have two choices:

1. Wait for 30 days for the deleted project to be removed from your account.
2. Undelete one of your projects and continue with that project.
3. Request a project limit quota increase. Google might ask you to make an advance payment to increase your quota.

[Project quota requests](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en)

Comment: I thought that just by shutting down the project it would free the quota. Since I'm just experimenting with the platform, restoring a project seems the best option for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like deleting projects with your "billable account" active on it, disables you to create new projects with your billable account. However, restoring the project, disabling billing under "Billing projects", and then deleting them again (not required), allowed me to continue creating more projects with the same billing account. It seems like I can have 4 concurrent billable projects before reaching the quota

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/538666)